# df.append() flattens MultiIndex... is that right?

Tags: python, pandas

Having browsed other threads relating to appending to a pandas dataframe, row by row I have read up on [***concat and append***](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) and [***setting with enlargement***](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#setting-with-enlargement) but still have this funny problem where is I create an empty DF with a `MultiIndex` and then append to it, the `MultIndex` appears to be flattened to a normal `Index`. To go back to a `MultiIndex`, at the end of all my row appends I must reset the index. Is this meant to work this way or am I going about this in a rather odd fashion?

I am using Pandas 0.16.2. NumPy as 1.9.2. Python 2.7.3

```
~$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2013, 05:46:21) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> np.__version__
'1.9.2'
>>> pd.__version__
'0.16.2'
```

Ubuntu version (running on VirtualBox) is

```
~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
```

Example below taken from the pandas MultiIndex docs with my own little bit at the end which demonstrates what I'm seeing...

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> colMultiIndex = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([ ["bar", "baz", "foo", "qux"], ["one", "two"] ])
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3,8), index = ["A", "B", "C"], columns=colMultiIndex )
```

Inspecting the columns I get back a `MultiIndex` as I'd expect and I can index using the "outer" column name:

```
>>> print df.columns
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'bar', u'baz', u'foo', u'qux'], [u'one', u'two']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]])
```

So, now I append another row. Now, here, maybe I am doing this in a round about fashion?? The reason I ask is that Pandas appears to collapse the `MultiIndex` into an `Index`...

```
>>> df2 = df.append(pd.Series(np.random.randn(1,8)[0], index=colMultiIndex), ignore_index=True)
>>> print df2.columns
Index([(u'bar', u'one'), (u'bar', u'two'), (u'baz', u'one'), (u'baz', u'two'),
       (u'foo', u'one'), (u'foo', u'two'), (u'qux', u'one'), (u'qux', u'two')],
      dtype='object')
```

The above shows this problem. I can no longer index as I'd expect. To solve this I must do the following:

```
>>> df2.columns = colMultiIndex
>>> print df2.columns
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'bar', u'baz', u'foo', u'qux'], [u'one', u'two']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]])
```

Should I have to do this or am I doing this the wrong way? I've been googling but can't find a solution and don't really see why append isn't happy.

**EDIT**

Very interestingly this works if I do it on my windows machine...

```
C:\Users\jimbo>python
Python 2.7.8 |Anaconda 2.1.0 (32-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2014, 15:13:35) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://binstar.org
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> np.__version__
'1.9.0'
>>> pd.__version__
'0.14.1'
>>> colMultiIndex = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([ ["bar", "baz", "foo", "qux"], ["one", "two"] ])
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3,8), index = ["A", "B", "C"], columns=colMultiIndex )
>>> print type(df.columns)
<class 'pandas.core.index.MultiIndex'>

>>> df2 = df.append(pd.Series(np.random.randn(1,8)[0], index=colMultiIndex), ignore_index=True)    
>>> print type(df2.columns)
<class 'pandas.core.index.MultiIndex'>
```

Even after updating the libraries to be 1.9.2 for numpy and 0.16.2 for pandas on the windows box, still the same result... works as expected.

Comment: Yep, sure, give me a minute (doh just deleted cells... will need to retype)....

Comment: Okay, posted copy and pastable code :)

Comment: What version pandas are you using? this works for me in `0.16.2`: 
`MultiIndex(levels=[['bar', 'baz', 'foo', 'qux'], ['one', 'two']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]])
MultiIndex(levels=[['bar', 'baz', 'foo', 'qux'], ['one', 'two']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]])`

Comment: That is strange! I have the same version \*puzzled\*

Comment: Ah should have been `columns=colMultiIndex` not `columns=index` btw. have edited question. Was a typo but result still the same. The only other library being used is numpy and thats at 1.9.2

Comment: Same as @EdChum, this works for me with 0.16.2 pandas and 1.9.2 for numpy.

Comment: I'm using pandas 0.16.2 python 3.3.4 64-bit and numpy 1.9.2

Comment: What platform are you guys on?

Comment: Works for me too on pandas 0.15.2, numpy 1.9.2, and python 2.7.6 on Ubuntu 4.8.2.

Comment: Works on Pandas 0.16.2, NumPy 1.9.2, Python 2.7.6